# Problem reflection between the floor and the room

Tags: modeling, reflection

I don't understand why I have the red colour on the white wall. It seems to come from the floor, a red carpet. I would like to remove this colour and keep the wall white. Do you know how to do this?

I use Cycles, and put a denoise to remove the fireflyes.

I put the picture of the scene, and my shadering for both.
[image]
Room

[image]
Floor

[image]
Wall

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Actually that's how it is in real life, here is a real photograph:

[image: red floor]

Light bounces off colored surfaces and the color gets spilled onto other surfaces. To get rid of it you can do one of two things, disadvantage is both are unrealistic:

1. Go to the *Object Properties* > *Visibility* > *Ray Visibility* and disable *Diffuse* and *Glossy*. This way the red color floor is not "visible" for the walls and they don't get red. Problem is, no light bounces off the floor onto the walls and they stay very dark.

[image: bounce light disabled]

2. Another option would be to create a material for the floor where you use a *Mix RGB* node to switch between white and red, and as a mix factor you take a *Light Path* node and use the *Ray Depth* output. This way only watching the floor directly shows the red color, the other objects "see" the white color. Advantage is, there is bounce light brightening the walls.

[image: ray depth]

Comment: Thanks a lot
It works.

Answer (score -1):

Your wall has the roughness less than 0.5 I guess that's why it is reflecting. Increase it, you'll get the desired result.

Comment: Even rough surfaces bounce off light, a bright saturated red will illuminate the walls with red even with a roughness of 1 and a specular value of 0.

Comment: You are right, that's why I said only to increase some roughness so that it would get the some realistic effect as light bounces from object to another object. Applying a Texture to the wall and then making the roughness a little high will make it look more natural, it will have little bit of red reflection as well.

Comment: I would suggest you try it for yourself. Since dielectric materials have a colorless reflection, actually increasing the roughness will increase the bounce of colored light instead of colorless reflection. So contrary to your guess decreasing the roughness would help more than increasing, but still won't "keep the wall white" as asked for in the question.

Comment: I see, thanks for the Info, since I'm still learning, this was quite helpful

Comment: Hey both,
Thanks for your help. I have tried to decrease and increase the roughness, the specular, ect,... nothing was working.